# How do three.js transforms and CSS3 3D-transforms correspond?

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, three.js, transform

I am working on an [open source tool](https://github.com/mhelvens/apinatomy) for navigating and visualizing human anatomy.

The main object of interest is a 'chessboard' taking up most of the screen. Dragging the board around performs certain CSS3 3D-transforms. A 3D object (a head, in the example below) is shown hovering over the board, rendered with three.js.

[image]

[image]

The transformation of the head is synchronized with that of the board. But this is currently a very imperfect synchronization, realized by trial-and-error.

How do the 'CSS 3D world' and the 'three.js/WebGL 3D world' correspond? For example, where is the 'camera' in the CSS world? Is there a way to synchronize the two properly? Even better, is there a library?

Comment: They do synchronize, but not with Chrome 34.0.1847.116, at least on OSX. Try hacking http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_sandbox.html. You should be able to create a `CSS3DObject` and a `PlaneGeometry` that line up perfectly, assuming the same camera is used to render both.

Comment: @WestLangley Hmmm, they seem to still be in sync on the dev branch. Just that example doesn't have the background color change. I'll update it.

Comment: @WestLangley: Thanks! Your pointers helped me out a bunch. I learned more about this technique from [this link](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/). If you'd like to submit an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @mrdoob It does seem to be working on Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/uM2NS/

Comment: @WestLangley heh, nice example :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do synchronize. Try hacking http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_sandbox.html.

You should be able to create a `CSS3DObject` and a `PlaneGeometry` that line up perfectly, assuming the same camera is used to render both.

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

mesh.position.copy( object.position );
mesh.rotation.copy( object.rotation );
mesh.scale.copy( object.scale );

scene.add( mesh );
```

In fact, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L9cUN/

three.js r.66